# RLC equivalent model and Impedance Smith Chart

Tags: impedance, measurement, passive-networks, microwave, smith-chart

I have done **some impedance measurements on an unknown 1 port device**. I have measured its impedance at different frequencies (from 10 MHz to 600 MHz) and I have seen it on the normalized (on 50 Ohm) Impedance Smith Chart:

[image]

**At Low frequencies we are at the short circuit point (left). Then, the device offers an inductive impedance, until, at about f0 = 470 MHz, we arrive at the real axis (right)**. It seems it arrives at the open point but it is not: if you see the following graph you see that the impedance is, obviously, purely real, but not infinite. It is equal to about 471 Ohm (absolute value).

[image]

You may see these results also in the following graphs (the first one contains real and imaginary parts of the impedance, while the second one its absolute value).

[image]

[image]

So, at f0 the devices resonates and offers a purely real impedance. Now my question is: **which is the equivalent RLC circuit of this device according to this analysis?**

Precisely:

- from the Smith Chart I may get the value of L: I should take the Imaginary Part of Zin at low frequencies (in which the device is almost purely inductive) and divide by 2*pi*f.
- from the Smith Chart I may get the value of R (it is 471 Ohm, as told before)
- from the Smith Chart I may get the value of C (at high frequencies, where the device is almost purely capacitive)

So, which is the equivalent model? A parallel RLC, a series RLC?
Moreover, at f0, does the device offer a parallel resonance, or a series Resonance? **I have been told that if I measure R,L,C through the Impedance Smith Chart, they are the values of the RLC series model**, but I am not sure about it because I can also do my measurements on the Impedance Smith Chart for a device which is not a RLC series circuit. For instance, something like that:

[image]

Moreover, I'd say it cannot be an RLC series circuit, because at low frequency we are at short circuit point, and not open circuit point.

Comment: You should just play around with some calculations or with a simulator, and see what kind of trace your circuit makes on the Smith chart. Then you'll know right away whether it matches your measurement or not.

Comment: Good Idea. I have done now a simulation with the impedance of a Series RLC circuit (Zin = R + jomegaL - j(1/omegaC)) but the path of the Smith Chart is different (in fact it starts at the open position and arrives at the short position). But you have made me think of a possible solution.

Comment: Maybe the solution is that with this kind of measurements we model the device with a series RLC circuit, but if the original device is not a series RLC circuit, we will get some frequency terms in R, L, C (I am thinking now at the equivalence formulas with Q factors, which contain omega). So this may explain the fact that the starting point is not the open point as an RLC circuit with R,L,C constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That characteristic looks awfully like a parallel RLC circuit. At resonance the LC part becomes infinity and, because it is shunted with R, the effective impedance is R, possibly a 470 ohm resistor. At DC and low frequencies the inductor dominates with its low impedance and, if you went significantly higher than 1 GHz the parallel capacitance would dominate and start to act as a low impedance shunt.

Below is just a convenient graph I found for a parallel RLC circuit: -
[image]

The difference between series and parallel resonance is shown side-by-side here: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://www.murata.com/en-global/products/emc/emifil/knowhow/basic/chapter03-p1).

Answer (score 0):

I keep looking but have not found graphs showing the impedances of circuits at various vales of l&c. If the reactances of the L or C are higher supposedly the impedance seen at resonance will be h

Comment: Hi there! I'm not following you here, are you trying to give an answer or some sort of comment?